# C# FirebaseDataBase API - Real Time Get Data into a List

Tags: c#, wpf, api, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I´m new in this topic about Firebase in C#, the online documetation is bad, I only find 2 (FireSharp and FireBaseDataBase) API for connect my Desktop App with Firebase and also I try to connect my app with JSON HttpRequest. In all the case when i try to PUT, UPDATE, DELETE, the response time delay 4 seconds and i´m sure that my internet have a good Connection.
 ***On the other hand and as a main question*** *(using the API FirebaseDataBase for C# WPF)* is why i can´t put the real time data in a List(). **First I try to do this.**

```
//Example//` 
public void StreamData()
 {
    List<Dinosaur> group= new  List<Dinosaur>();
    var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/");
    var observable = firebase
    .Child("dinosaurs")
    .AsObservable<Dinosaur>()
    .Subscribe(d => group.Add(d.Object));
  }
```

But the problem here is that "group" dont Add "d.Object".
**Then I try to use this code:**

```
 public void StreamData()
    {           
        List<Persona> g = new List<Persona>();
        var observable = firebaseClient.Child("Information").AsObservable<Persona>();
        var t=  observable.ObserveOnDispatcher().AsObservableCollection();
    }
```

But I have this problem :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The current thread has no
>   Dispatcher associated with it.'

In summary i try to get a real time data from Firebase with the API FireBaseDataBase, as a List() because i want to insert in my Datagrid.